# Moving partition in Windows

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

I've been reading about the structure of the partition table in Windows and there is one aspect I wasn't able to figure out - when moving a partition, does in only change the data in the partition table or does it physically move the data on the adjacent partition on the drive?
Currently I have following partition scheme:

[image: Partition scheme]

I want to expand OS partition by moving Unalocated space to the left. If I do that, what happens to the info contained in the adjacent Data partition? I'm asking to evaluate how safe this operation is - i.e. if the bits itself are being moved, the chance of data corruption would probably be higher rather then if it only changes the corresponding partition position in the partition table.

Comment: You cannot simply move the unallocated partition to the left…

Comment: I can, with the help of third-party tools. If I understand it correctly, it works by modifying the partition's position in the partition table.

Comment: No; it works by moving the data; which is why it’s important to backup the data

Comment: So there is no way to modify the position in the partition table?

Comment: You can change the order of the partition entries in the partition table, but it won't achieve what you want, because for a partition, it can only makes use of one contiguous range of logical blocks, which is why you need to make those that are contiguous to the partition you want to extend free by moving the data on them to those that are not.

Comment: `modifying the partition's position` means moving the whole partition data to the new position and then modify the position of the partition in the partition table to point to the new location

Comment: Yes you can move it but requires 3rd party partitioning software. >>>>>https://www.paragon-software.com/us/free/pm-express/